# php как округлить число в зависимости от количества 0 после запятой

Tags: php, round

как округлить число в зависимости от количества 0 после запятой?

Приходит случайное число, типа строка например 0,00004123 или 0,03565

каким должно быть условие:

если нолей после запятой 1 выводить 0,03

если нолей после запятой 2 выводить 0,006

если нолей после запятой 4 выводить 0,00004

и так далее.

Спасибо.

Comment: умножайте на 10 пока больше 0 не получите, до того знака и округлите

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '0,00004123';

$index = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); ++$i) {
    ++$index;
    
    if ($str[$i] !== ',' && $str[$i] !== '0')
        break;
}

echo substr($str, 0, $index);
```

---

Можно всячески улучшить: например зная заранее, что будет `0,`  можно начинать цикл сразу с индекса 2 и также по дефолту в `$index` занести это смещение

Comment: либо заменить `^([0.]+\d).*` на `$1`

Comment: @teran что-что, а вот регулярки, в виду их магичности и неясности для большинства - я рекомендую использовать только в крайних случаях)